# How to customize Element Plus el-table

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vuejs3, element-plus

I'm new to Element Plus and have a little problem using el-table. Can anyone with experience using Element Plus give me an idea or something? I use VueJS and Element Plus. Thanks everyone in advance.

**My data:**

```
[
    {
        no: "F",
        type: "Approval",
        name: "Master",
        status: "Approved",
        processDate: "01-01-2024 10:22",
        comment: "Helloo world!"
    },
    {
        no: "G",
        type: "Approval",
        name: "Master",
        status: "Rejected",
        processDate: "01-01-2024 10:22",
        comment: "Comment content 1"
    },
    {
        no: "H",
        type: "Draft",
        name: "Master",
        status: "Rejected",
        processDate: "01-01-2024 10:22",
        comment: "Comment content 2"
    }
]
```

**Original code:**

```
            <table class="w-full">
                <thead class="sticky top-0">
                    <tr class="title text-center bg-indigo-200">
                        <th class="p-10">No</th>
                        <th class="p-10">Type</th>
                        <th class="p-10">Name</th>
                        <th class="p-10">Status</th>
                        <th class="p-10">Process Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="overflow-y-auto h-96">
                    <template v-for="(item, index) in props.approvalData" :key="index">
                        <tr class="content-info text-center">
                            <td class="px-6 py-2">{{ item.no }}</td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-2">{{ item.type }}</td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-2">{{ item.name }}</td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-2">{{ item.status }}</td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-2">{{ item.processDate }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr v-if="item.comment" class="content-cmt bg-gray-100">
                            <td class="px-6 py-2"></td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-2 text-center">Comment</td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-2" colspan="4">{{ item.comment }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Expected results:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWSYd.png)

```
    <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="no" label="No"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="type" label="Type"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="status" label="Status"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="processDate" label="Process Date"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="comment" label="Comment"></el-table-column>
    </el-table>
```

Comment: So you're just trying to replicate the look of your `<table>` code that is styled with... I think tailwind CSS... in your new code with `<el-table>`.  Is that right?  You can just copy the CSS. el-table, if you inspect the DOM, is made up of table, tr, td elements... so same styling can be applied manually.  You just need to do the work of copying the styles that the tailwind classes were providing you previously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my problem is not with my ideas, but when I iterate through the fields, when I get to the comment field it takes up 1 row. With <table> I can easily control whether the comment field takes up 1 row. But <el-table> accepts data and spreads the data into columns


Ex:
const xxx = [
{date: "xxx",
name: "xxx"}
]


   <el-table :data="xxx" border style="width: 100%">
     <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="180" />
     <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180" />
   </el-table>

Comment: I have image in Expected results above